# How can I easily determine which pseudo-terminal device a terminal emulator has been assigned?

Tags: terminal

I'm writing a little curses program and I want to redirect `stderr` to another terminal. However, the only way of determining the correct `/dev/pts/X` device to redirect to that I know of is to echo text to them one at a time until it shows up where I want.

Is there a command which will give me what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the `tty` command, which prints the file name of the terminal connected to standard input.